# Postgres: how to get number of docs fetched per hour?

Tags: postgresql

I have a history table that contains a starttime as bigint and documents fetched or ingested.
I need to calculate how many documents get handled each hour every day.
I created this but it doesn't work quite right and I do NOT need the running totals.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   EXTRACT(hour from TO_TIMESTAMP(starttime)) as hour
  ,count(*) OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(hour from TO_TIMESTAMP(starttime))) as count
FROM   repohistory where activitytype like '%ingest%' OR activitytype like '%fetch%' and  resultcode = 'OK'  
ORDER  BY 1;
```

How do I do this?

I'm using Postgres v9.1.13

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp(starttime)) as hour, count(*) as total
from repohistory
where
    (activitytype like '%ingest%' or activitytype like '%fetch%')
    and  resultcode = 'ok'
group by 1
order by 1
```

Notice that your condition is likely wrong

Comment: Thank you! I just had to divide the starttime by 1000 and capitalize OK it worked perfectly!